# Unity does not resolve the dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I use Unity with Unity.MVC5. The class that registers the types and the dependency resolver is as below:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container
            .RegisterType<ILogger, Nlogger>()
            .RegisterType<IDataAccessLayer, SqlDataAccessLayer>()
            .RegisterType<IEventBusiness, EventBusiness>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    }
}
```

And here is my Global.asax code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  
}
```

In one of my controllers I have a property like this:

```
[Dependency]
public IEventBusiness EventBusiness { get; set; }
```

I expect that this property be set automatically by Unity but it's always null. Can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might also try supplying an `InjectionProperty` config on the registration. Alternatively, why not try constructor injection instead?

Comment: Are you registering your controllers into the container?

Comment: @TylerOhlsen, no I don't register the controllers. Do I have to?  Inside the controller when I check DependencyResolver.Current, it gives me the correct instance of UnityContainer with all the registered types.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your help guys. I removed Unity.MVC5 and installed Unity plus Unity.Bootstrapper instead. Now everything works fine.  I followed this article to resolve the issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx